# How To use setOnItemClickListner multiple times in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

Well i'm creating a ListView and i want each item in this ListView to take the user to something specific. can anyone give me the code or just some tips?

Comment: How about you post your code and show what you have tried so far. The people here aren't here to do your work for you.

Comment: Please share you code if there is any

Answer (score 1):

Add an `OnItemClickListener` to your `ListView`:

```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    if(((TextView)view).getText().toString().equals("item1")){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "item1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }         
                }
            });
```